# Protected member conflict with overloading operator

Tags: c++, class, inheritance, protected

I have the following classes:

```
class Base {
protected:
    int myint;        
};

class Derived : public Base {
public:
    bool operator==(Base &obj) {
        if(myint == obj.myint)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
};
```

But when I compile it, it gives the following errors:

> `int Base::myint` is protected within this context

I thought that protected variables are accessible from the derived class under a public inheritance. What is causing this error?

Comment: Try changing the argument of `operator==` from `Base&` to `Derived&`. (or `Derived const&` if you don't need to modify it)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Derived` can access protected members of `Base` on all instances of `Derived` only. But `obj` isn't an instance of `Derived`, it's an instance of `Base` - so access is forbidden. The following would compile fine, since now `obj` is a `Derived`

```
class Derived : public Base {
public:
    bool operator==(const Derived& obj) const {
        return myint == obj.myint;
    }
};
```